# Are these two Feynman diagrams different?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, symmetry, feynman-diagrams

I am a little confused about the symmetry of Feynman diagrams. As far as I understand, Feynman diagrams are not symmetric with respect to exchange of external points or momentums if the diagrams are not symmetric. But just to be sure, would these diagrams be considered different diagrams?

[image]

Comment: They're the same diagram in that they lead to the same loop integral as a function of external momenta.